# Why isn't there more interest in "large powerset axioms"?

Tags: set-theory, soft-question, large-cardinals

By a large powerset axiom, let us mean informally an axiom that says that for some cardinal numbers $\kappa$, we have that $2^\kappa$ is somehow "large" or "difficult to access from below." For example: whenever $\kappa$ is infinite,

1. $2^\kappa$ is regular
2. $2^\kappa$ is a fixed-point of $\aleph$
3. $2^\kappa$ is weakly inaccessible
4. $2^\kappa$ is weakly hyper-inaccessible
5. $2^\kappa$ is weakly Mahlo

etc. (I do not know if these are all consistent).

Let us also include more ambiguous cases in our definition of "large powerset axioms," like:

1. the map $\kappa \mapsto 2^\kappa$ is injective
2. for every infinite set $X$, the powerset of $X$ has a subchain of cardinality $2^{|X|}$

Anyway, looking at the literature, there doesn't seem to be a lot of interest in these kinds of axioms, as compared to the amount of attention given to large cardinal axioms.

> **Question.** Is there any particular reason for this lack of interest? For example, are there conservativity results showing that
>   such axioms are "very weak" which might explain the lack of interest?

Comment: What is a subchain of a powerset?

Comment: @MonroeEskew, if $X$ is a set, then by a subchain of the powerset of $X$ I just mean a subset $C$ of $\mathcal{P}(X)$ that is totally ordered by $\subseteq$ restricted to $C$.

Comment: Is $\kappa\mapsto 2^\kappa$ being injective really a "large powerset axiom" ? This is a more GCH-like property and therefore seems to be in some sense "orthogonal" to largeness questions.

Comment: @JohannesHahn, I fully agree that it is a dubious axiom to list as "large powerset." However I included it for the following reason; firstly, assuming this axiom, we see that $\kappa < \nu$ implies $2^\kappa < 2^\nu$. Secondly, assuming also that for all infinite $\kappa$, we have that $2^\kappa$ is weakly inaccessible; then if $\kappa < \nu$ are infinite cardinals, we may deduce that $2^\kappa < 2^\nu$, hence since $2^\nu$ is weakly inaccessible, there is a huge wilderness of cardinals between $2^\kappa$ and $2^\nu$.

Comment: @user18921 Well sort of... If one assumes GCH (which implies injectivity of the power function) than the "wilderness" between $2^\kappa$ and $2^\nu$ is exactly as wild as the cardinals between $\kappa$ and $\nu$, so there is nothing new in that sense.

Comment: @JohannesHahn, oh I fully agree. In the presence of GCH, injectivity of the aforementioned function should not be considered a large powerset sentence. However, in the presence of sufficiently strong large powerset axioms, the injectivity sentence certainly acts like a large powerset axiom. By the way, the same can be said of regularity; GCH proves that every $2^\kappa$ is regular, so this is not really a large powerset sentence. However in the presence of the axioms to the effect that "$2^\kappa$ is a limit cardinal," suddenly it *is* a large powerset sentence.

Comment: Just a minor historical comment: the hypothesis that, for every infinite $\kappa$, $2^\kappa$ is the least weakly inaccessible $ > \kappa$ seems due to Kurepa, Sull'ipotesi del continuo (Italian)  Univ. e Politec. Torino. Rend. Sem. Mat. 18 1958/1959 11-20 [(downloadable here)](http://seminariomatematico.dm.unito.it/rendiconti/cartaceo/18/Volume%2018%20(1958-59)%20-%2002%20-%20Sull%20ipotesi%20del%20continuo.pdf) So there has always been interest in hypotheses under which the powerset function is "large".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suppose there is some interest in propositions implying large powerset. For example, a classical question at the infancy of set theory and real analysis was whether there is a probability measure on the unit interval that extends Lebesgue measure, in which every set is measurable.  This implies that the continuum is weakly Mahlo, Rowbottom, etc.  It's also equiconsistent with a two-valued measurable cardinal.

The stronger interest in large cardinals is surely due to the empirical fact that they form a coherent system that measures the relative consistency of everything.  It's not clear that large powerset type propositions have a similar property. Some of the things you mention have no strength, like the continuum function is injective. It follows from GCH and it's negation is easily forced.

Related fact: If $2^\omega$ is real-valued measurable, the continuum function is not injective.  $2^\kappa = 2^\omega$ for all $\kappa < 2^\omega$.  This is due to Prikry, and a proof can be found in chapter 22 of Jech.

Answer (score 7):

Contrary to your remarks, I believe that there is interest in these kind of principles. Let me mention a few places where they come up.

One example arises in connection with $\text{MP}_{\text{ccc}}$, the maximality principle for c.c.c. forcing, which implies that the continuum $2^\omega$ is enormous. The maximality principle says that any statement $\varphi$ that is forceable (in this case by c.c.c. forcing) such that it remains true in all forcing extensions (again c.c.c.) is already true in $V$. Under this axiom, since we can add more Cohen reals, and further c.c.c. forcing will not collapse the continuum, it follows under $\text{MP}_{\text{ccc}}$ that $2^\omega$ is larger than any cardinal that we can describe in a c.c.c.-absolute manner (for otherwise we could push it larger than that cardinal and violate maximality). You can read more at:

- *Joel David Hamkins*, [**A simple maximality principle**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2178/jsl/1052669062), *J. Symbolic Logic* **68** (2003), no. 2, 527--550, [blog post](http://jdh.hamkins.org/maximalityprinciple/).
- *Joel D. Hamkins and W. Hugh Woodin*, [**The necessary maximality principle for c.c.c. forcing is equiconsistent with a weakly compact cardinal**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/malq.200410045), *MLQ Math. Log. Q.* **51** (2005), no. 5, 493--498, [blog post](http://jdh.hamkins.org/nmpccc/).

Another example arises in connection with $\text{RA}(\text{ccc})$, the resurrection axiom for c.c.c. forcing. For example, the following theorem is proved in J.D. Hamkins, T.A. Johnstone, [Resurrection axioms and uplifting cardinals](http://jdh.hamkins.org/resurrection-axioms-and-uplifting-cardinals/), Archive for Math Logic, 52/53, 2014.

**Theorem.** The resurrection axiom RA(ccc) implies that the continuum
$\frak{c}$ is a weakly inaccessible cardinal, even weakly hyper-inaccessible, a limit
of such cardinals and so on. In particular, RA(ccc) implies that CH fails
spectacularly.

Answer (score 7):

A number of such "large or complex power set" axioms were considered in the following paper of Gaisi Takeuti:

Hypotheses on power set. In: Axiomatic Set Theory (Proc. Symp. Pure Math, XIII) Part I, pp.439-446  (MR 0300901)